# Error in Connecting to TFS with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

[image]

This is the error I get when I try to connect to TFS. The only change that I had made to Windows Live account was to enable "Two-Step verification".

Visual Studio isn't giving me an option to change the credentials in case I may have entered it wrong the first try I made to connect.

I was able to connect to TFS from another system.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try clearing your temp internet folder etc. first [see here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6fb8272b-df51-42c2-ad3d-97a730a284cb/tf31003-when-trying-to-connect-to-team-foundation-service-from-vs-2012?forum=TFService) for a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also encountering same error which is resolved after cleaning up cache.
Try after deleting cache from following location in your system : 
C:\Users\gaurav1\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation

make sure you close all visual studio instances before deleting cache.

Thanks,
Gaurav